# Getting error while using LoggedIn() in CakePHP 2.6.6

Tags: php, cakephp

How can we get user id like using below statement. when i using below statement, i am getting error called missing [ ....., please correct it.

```
$this->request->data['Category']['user_id']=AuthComponent::user()['id'];
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need save id.
Secondly, use `$this->Auth->user('id')` to get id

Don't forget `public $components = array('Auth');`